# In terms of the derivative f' of f express the derivative of f(3x)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

In terms of the derivative f' of f express the derivative of f(3x).
The solution is: $\frac{d}{dx} f(3x)=(f'(3x))(3)=3*f'(3x)$

I don't understand the question. The derivative of f is 3. f' is 3. 3*f' is 9?

We want to express the derivative of f in terms of f'. The derivative of f is 3.
What is the question asking?

Comment: "The derivative of $f$ is $3$". Why ?

Comment: What do you mean by why? If you derivative it, you get 3. Is that wrong or what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that, as asked, the question does not mention any reason that $f'=3$. So either something is missing in your post, either there is no reason to affirm that $f'=3$.

Answer (score 1):

The chain rule, which says what is the derivative of a composition of functions. Here we have

$$f(x)\;,\;\;h(x)=3x\implies f\circ h(x)=f(h(x))$$

and the chain rule tells us that $\;\left(f\circ h(x)\right)'=(f(h(x))' = f'(h(x)) \cdot h'(x)\;$

In this case, $\;f'(h(x))=f'(3x)\;$ , and $\;h'(x)=(3x)'=3\;$ , so at the end

$$(f(3x))'=f'(3x)\cdot 3=3f'(3x)$$

Comment: Thank you! I am not sure I understand though. What is it 3f'(3x) actually means? 3 is the derivative of f, and f'(3x) is 3 too. How does that make sense?

Comment: Exactly what it is written: it is the derivative of $\;f\;$ at the point $\;h(x)=3x\;$, namely $\;f'(h(x))= f'(3x)\;$,  times the derivative of $\;h(x)=3x\;$ at the point $\;x\;$, namely $\;3\;$ . Thus, for example, the derivative of $\;f(3x)\;$ at $\;x=4\;$ is $\;3f'(3\cdot4)=3f'(12)\;$ , and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what is confusing you is that there is a difference between $f'(3x)$ and the derivative of $g(x)=f(3x)$. The former refers to the gradient function of $f$, evaluated at a point which we label as $3x$; the latter refers to the gradient of the composite function $x \mapsto f(3x)$, evaluated at the point $x$. To give an example, if $f(x)=\sin(x)$, then $f'(x)=\cos (x)$, and so $f'(3x)=\cos(3x)$. By contrast, if $g(x)=\sin(3x)$, then $g'(x)=3\cos(3x)$ by the chain rule. Just to drive the point home, the definition of $f'(3x)$ is
$$
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(3x+h)-f(3x)}{h} \, ,
$$
whereas the definition of $g'(x)$ is
$$
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(3(x+h))-f(3x)}{h} \, .
$$
Here, we are dealing with $y=f(3x)$. The chain rule states that
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du} \cdot \frac{du}{dx} \, .
$$
If we set $u=3x$, then $y=f(u)$, and so $dy/du = f'(u)$. Also, $du/dx = 3$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx} &= f'(u) \cdot 3 \\
&= 3f'(3x) \, .
\end{align}